# Add NULL column very large MySQL table - does it take much longer than adding to a small table?

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table

Logic says it should be really fast to add a `NULL` column even if adding to a very large (~800 GB) table.

Obviously if the `ALTER TABLE` has a `NOT NULL` for the new column it will take a long time, but how about for `NULL` columns? How does it compare to altering a small table?

I'm on MySql 5.5.

Thanks!

Comment: How about timing it on your system?

Comment: Logic is ... surprising... sometimes.

Comment: @Go I would, but obviously I'm hearing what others that might have attempted this have to say about their experiences on MySQL. Else I wouldn't post a question, would I? :)

Comment: @bish exactly, therefore the question haha

Comment: alternate would be create a new _temp table with new column, copy the data over, rename old table, rename new table, do verification, drop old table if needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL implements [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html) as a table recreation.

> In most cases, `ALTER TABLE` makes a temporary copy of the original table (...)
>   incorporates the alteration into the copy, deletes the original table,
>   and renames the new one.

The manual goes on and explains what "most cases" means. Basically: adding, removing, and redefining columns.

Only the table size matters, the column type has little to no impact in terms of execution time.

Comment: And mysql is notorious for being extremely slow when adding columns to large tables. I've seen it take literally hours for only 10's of millions of rows.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I saw this in the docs but wasn't sure what they meant by "most cases".

Comment: Yeah, I too had to read it twice to figure this out. In fact they provide a list of operations where "an in-place ALTER TABLE is possible that does not require a temporary table".